# command + Y to delete the entire line is not working in Intellij Idea 2017 version

Tags: intellij-idea

Previously COMMAND + Y shortcut key is used to delete the entire line in IntellIj Idea 2016.

Currently the same shortcut is not working in latest version 2017.

What is the new key for this.

Comment: What key bindings are you using between the two versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `delete line` action is definitely supported in Intellij 2017.2.1

You can check the key binding from `Preferences > Keymap`.

Here's a screenshot showing the binding for the Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap on Intellij v2017.2.1

[image]

Yours may differ, depending on what keymap you have chosen but you can use this approach to identify the key mapping for your setup.

Comment: glytching - I to have the same binding. Command + X is working. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Command + Y` just type `Command + delete` key it will delete the line in IntellIj.